# passing variable values between HTML pages

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I created this HTML calendar, when the user selects a date, JS returns a value like this:

```
<li class ="num" id="day6" onclick = "return checkDate(6)"> </li>
```

I called the value in my external JS file:

```
function checkDate(a) {
    a = dayNum;
    alert(dayNum);
    day = dayNum- start_day2; }
```

The alert works, but when I try to load this same script on another page, it alerts "undefined". I assume it's because of the reloading the value for `a` is not set. Is there a way around this? Sticking to Javascript only please because that's the only Language I know fairly well.

Thanks.

Comment: can you write code you are using to load this script in another page

Comment: I think daynum needs to = a, otherwise you are overwriting the variable you are pushing in. second start_day2 is never set

Comment: When you leave a page, *all* JavaScript variables are unloaded.  You need to use a cookie, localStorage, or similar.

Comment: Look into `LocalStorage`

Comment: <body onload = "checkDate()" >

Comment: Easiest way is probably setting a cookie.  `jQuery.cookie` is a great lightweight jQuery plugin that makes doing this incredibly simple (just one line of code to store the value and another to retrieve it).  [See here.](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: could anyone show me an example using JCookies?

Comment: Check out [google.com](http://google.com) for a great way to seach for information on the internet... You might try searching for "_javascript cookie simple example_" or something like that.

Comment: can someone give me an example please? I'm really having some trouble here understanding and applying.

Comment: It seems like cookies only work with submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDate(a) {
    var dayNum, day, start_day2;
    dayNum = a;
    start_day2 = null; //no value specified in given code
    alert(dayNum);
    day = dayNum- start_day2; 
}
```

Short cut to what you've shown

```
function checkDate(a) {
    alert(a);
}
```

Comment: Yea I know, that was specified in my code, but i just put it there as an example.

Comment: yea but I want the value of a to alert when called in another HTML file